# Bootstrap 5 Radio toggle buttons btn-check with btn-sm class

Tags: radio-button, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use the **btn-check** class along with **btn-sm** to get smaller buttons but it ignores the small class. Am I missing something or is there another way to make the buttons smaller?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="row g-2 mx-2 my-2">
  <div class="btn-group col-6" role="group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check btn-sm" name="option" id="option-1" value="yes">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="option-1">Yes</label>
    
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check btn-sm" name="option" id="option-2" value="na">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="option-2">I Don't Know</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check btn-sm" name="option" id="option-3" value="no">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="option-3">No</label>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

1. Remove the `btn-sm` class from `<input>` elements.
2. Add the `btn-sm` class to the `<div class="btn-group col-6" role="group">` and all three `<label>` elements.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="row g-2 mx-2 my-2">
  <div class="btn-group col-6 btn-sm" role="group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-1" value="yes" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" for="option-1">Yes</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-2" value="na" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" for="option-2">I Don't Know</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-3" value="no" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" for="option-3">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just change the btn-group class in the div to btn-group-sm.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    


<div class="row g-2 mx-2 my-2">
  <div class="btn-group-sm col-6" role="group">
    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-1" value="yes" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="option-1">Yes</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-2" value="na" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary" for="option-2">I Don't Know</label>

    <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="option" id="option-3" value="no" />
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger" for="option-3">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```